# Arrays not counting correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I know I was just asking a question earlier *facepalm*

This is in Java coding by the way.

Well after everyones VERY VERY helpful advice (thank you guys alot)

I managed to get over half of the program running how I wanted.

Everything is pointing in the arrays where I want them to go. Now I just need to access the arrays so that It prints the correct information randomly.

This is the current code that im using:

http://pastebin.org/301483

The specific code giving me problems is this:

long aa;
    int abc;

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
 aa = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

 String str = Long.toString(aa);
 abc = Integer.parseInt(str);

 String[] userAnswer = new String[x];

 if(abc > x)
 {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number is too high. \nNumber Generator will reset.");
  break;
 }

 userAnswer[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Question "+quesNum+"\n"+questions[abc]+"\n\nA: "+a[abc]+"\nB: "+b[abc]+"\nC: "+c[abc]+"\nD: "+d[abc]);

 answer = userAnswer[i].compareTo(answers[i]);

 if(answer == 0)
 {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct. \nThe Correct Answer is "+answers[abc]+""+i);
 }
 else
 {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong. \n The Correct Answer is "+answers[abc]+""+i);
 }//else
```

Comment: can you phrase the problem as a question? It's not exactly clear what you need help with.

Comment: Not sure how to phrase the question...it just not working correctly. If you compile and run it youll see what I mean

Comment: What do you mean by "prints the correct information randomly"?  Do you want show your questions in a random order?

Comment: Yes, I want the random number generator to generate a number. The number cannot be greater then the number of questions the user wants so it loops and randomizes until it gets a correct digit. Then it pulls from the array the corresponding question to the place in array. For example if the random number is 2 it would pull from array[3] which is a question and then the answers each from the same number in other arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but I noticed this line:

```
aa = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
```

If you need a random `int` between `0` and `10` inclusive, it's much better to use:

> [`java.util.Random.nextInt(int n)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29): Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

You'd first create an instance elsewhere (you should only need to do this once in your application):

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Then, whenever you need a random integer between `0` and `10` inclusive, you do:

```
aa = r.nextInt(10+1);
```

You can just write `11`, but writing `10+1` perhaps have the added benefit of reminding readers that it's a half-open range.

---

Okay, I just noticed the following:

```
 aa = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
 String str = Long.toString(aa);
 abc = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

This makes very little sense. You should be able to just do:

```
 aa = r.nextInt(10+1);
 abc = (int) aa;
```

Though frankly I'm not sure if you really need these many variables in the first place. Perhaps you can just write:

```
 int aa = r.nextInt(10+1);
```

---

You also ought to consider using `String.format` instead of doing all these concatenations.

```
    System.out.println(
        String.format("%d + %d = %s", 3, 4, 7)
    ); // prints "3 + 4 = 7"
```

#### API links

- [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: you dont even realize the help you have just been. I have been looking for a way to randomize numbers for a LONG time. I never knew how. What more does that random do?

Comment: @Nick: see full API http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html ; it has Gaussian distribution, random `boolean`, random bits, random `byte[]`, random `long`, and of course, `double` between 0 and 1.

Comment: what all my books have ever told me was Math.random() which creates a random number 0.0 through 1.0 which is crazily inconvienent being how 1) its in data type long and 2) i have to multiply it and manipulate it in several ways to ev en get it to where I need it to be.

Comment: @Nick: listen to the other answers too about variable names.

Comment: @Nick: I think you can just write `if (userAnswer[i].equals(answers[i])) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Thanks...that shortened it and helped. Also, if you have time is there any easier place to talk. The time frame here is too wide

Answer (score 1):

In the future, use real variable names. `aa` and `abc` mean nothing and don't help convey what date the variable actually holds. Unless you are are dealing with coordinates, `x` is also a bad variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments on your code:

- Try to use **descriptive variable names**.  A variable named "x"
  doesn't mean much to the programmer
  reading your code.  For all he knows,
  it could be used to store the
  population of France.  What do you
  think a better name might be?
- Keep in mind the **scope of your
  variables** (where they are being
  used).  For example, if a variable is only being
  used in a for loop, then it should
  be declared in the for loop.  Where
  do you think the "qq" variable declaration should
  be moved to?